# Django 1.7 auth_user unique email

Tags: python, django

I have problem to create unique email field on the auth_user table

On Django 1.6 version 
I added that string to the huote/settings.py and everything work fine 
User._meta.get_field('email')._unique=True

On 1.7 version I try this example below because I have error
*django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.*

but it's not working

-- huote/apps.py --

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name="huote"

    def ready(self):
        User._meta.get_field('email')._unique=True
```

-- "huote/__init__.py" --

```
default_app_config = 'huote.apps.YourAppConfig'
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a custom migration to create the unique constraint on the database.

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/

you can:

- ovverride the migrations of the User model using [MIGRATION_MODULES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIGRATION_MODULES) but this probably will berak upgrades of django
- create a custom migration in yuor app using [runsql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/migration-operations/#runsql)

In any case you still need your code (`User._meta.get_field('email')._unique=True`) to keep django aligned.

Answer (score 0):

I create file in my app directory and add unique index for the table auth_user

*huote/migrations/0001_initial.py*

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

     dependencies = [
     ]

     operations = [
          migrations.RunSQL("create unique index unique_auth_user on auth_user(email);")
     ]
```